# npm run watch not concurrently starting both servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

```
"scripts": {   
    "server": " npm run watch --prefix server", 
    "client":" npm run start --prefix client",
    "watch":" npm run client & npm run server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

`npm run watch` only runs the first command (`npm run client`) before `&` operator.

Comment: I would recommend you look into [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently).

Answer (score 0):

install this package:https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all and then  "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js", where watch-css and start-js are npm scripts in my case